# Should someone "improve" an answer to include information given in other answers?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, attribution

I gave an answer to [this PERL question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449307/iterating-over-a-string-in-perl/24449485#24449485). My answer did not include every single method of solving the problem and is perhaps a traditional way of solving it instead of a more modern form. As you are no doubt aware with PERL, There Is More Than One Way To Do It.

My question is whether it is really appropriate for the (leading) answer to be edited **by someone else** to include information already given by other people answering the question. I want to be clear that I have no objection to useful extra information being added to answers, but that adding an entirely alternative method was not appropriate, especially as other answers had fully raised the issue.

Comment: unattributed copying could be considered [plagiarism](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plagiarism), so if you copy from some other answer, you better be forthright about this

Comment: I didn't do the copying in question - someone edited my answer and the edits were approved. I don't think my answer should have been edited by someone else in this way. I have modified my question to clarify the point.

Comment: I've rejected such edits in the past, and they ***should*** be rejected. The reviewers who approved that should be give a review ban. Oh wait, that wasn't a suggested edit. Anyways, yeah, you're not really supposed to change someone else's answer like that without permission.

Comment: The editor had 130k reputation and thus his edit didn't even go through the review queue...

Comment: @vogomatix your options then are either to rollback the edit, or add the attribution to the copied content. I'd personally pick based on criteria of what would look most valuable for future post readers